# What is Difference Between These Two Fence Posts?

Tags: fence, gate-post

I think I can ask this here?

To provide some better property security, I want/need to suspend a heavy chain between two posts that I plan to drive into ground across a driveway inlet.  I am looking at these two...:

[2" x 2" Standard-Duty Aluminum Fence Corner Post](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Barrette-Outdoor-Living-Natural-Reflections-2-in-x-2-in-x-8-7-8-ft-Black-Standard-Duty-Aluminum-Fence-Corner-Post-73002396/202898910)

[2" x 2" Standard-Duty Aluminum Fence Gate Post](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Barrette-Outdoor-Living-Natural-Reflections-Standard-Duty-2-in-x-2-in-x-8-7-8-ft-Black-Aluminum-Fence-Gate-Post-73002400/202898912)

...and can't figure out why one of them is **70%(!)** more expensive than the other even though as far as I can tell they are identical in all respects except one is for the fence corner (a couple of extra punch-outs, therefore a bit more involved, manufacturing-wise) and the other (the more expensive one) is for either side of a gate - exactly what I think I need.

I get the Econ 101 principle of supply-and-demand...no need to expound on that, and if that is only possible reason to account for this cost difference that has me confused, so be it.  ***But*** if there is a real difference in functionality or whatever -- beyond one is for a corner and one is for a gate -- that explains my confusion, then I am really interested in understanding that.

Comment: Consider galvanized steel, it's usually both cheaper and stronger than aluminum for this sort of work.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: yep.  The consideration(s) that had me look at these aluminum ones are that these already have cutouts I might/could thread chain through...I just can't fathom the cost difference between them.

Comment: @Ecnerwal:  But using galvanized steel posts, I'd need to weld something on (a bolt-on solution for suspending chain would probably be too easily defeated...right?).  So extra cost for "U" brackets, plus extra work for welding.  Also, I think that welding on galvanized steel is considered a no-no, in general, due to poisonous gases produced.  Obviously it can be done with proper PPE and outdoor set-up, but where I would be doing the welding is **both** indoors and a "shared space".  I am still open to the idea, though, as it was what I was originally considering.

Comment: There are plenty of bolt-on accessories for galvanized posts. "Staking" the nuts (deforming the bolt mechanincally to prevent unscrewing) and/or using Loctite red (very serious thread-locking compound) will make removal non-trivial. Using bolt-cutters or a battery-powered rotatry tool and cutoff disk on the chain is how the folks that routinely defeat these things will do that, unless liquid-nitrogen-shattering is still in style. It's not very much "security."

Comment: @Ecnerwal: yeah...that makes sense.  Whether I weld something onto a post or use the "staking a nut" (ouch!) approach to a bolt-on whatever, either way it becomes semi-permanent.  I get it is not absolute security against determined trespassers, but I expect it will sufficiently deter the more casual types.  And I'll be using a couple of trail cameras to supplement the chain gate, so at least I'll have some pics/vids of anyone attempting to actually break-in.  Thanks for the thoughts...they helped!

Answer (score 5):

Per the manufacturer, the gate post is heavier to support the weight of the gate.

> ... gate posts look similar to end posts, but are heavier duty to support the weight of your gate.

Comment: That makes sense and I had thought about that before posting but satisfied myself that they were equivalent in strength and construction from the "specifications" on the HD product pages that have them both weighing "5.2 lbs".  Sigh...

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's more expensive is addressed by RMDman. The reason it's *substantially* more expensive is explained by typical sales tactics. With systems like this the common components are often sold as loss leaders--at or even below cost to make the system price seem attractive. Specialty parts are then priced much higher because you don't tend to consider them until you're committed to the project.

Another example is with flooring, where transitions are often absurdly costly for their material involvement and low complexity. Even basic 2x4 and OSB lumber is sold near cost at big-box stores with the expectation that you'll also purchase all the expensive accessories and tools along with them.

Word to the wise: Plan and price your *entire* project before making a decision.